Showing compactness of particular subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$
I came across the following problem and I'm having trouble with a particular part.

Let $X = [0,1] \times \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $Z = \cup_{n=0}^{\infty} Z_{n} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$, where \begin{equation*} Z_{n} = \begin{cases}[0, 1] \times \{0\} & \text{ if } n = 0 \\ \{(x, x/n) \mid x \in [0,1]\} & \text{ if } n \geq 1.\end{cases}\end{equation*} Prove that $Z$ is a compact subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

In a previous question, I have shown that $f \colon X \rightarrow Z$ given by
\begin{equation*}
f(x, n) = 
\begin{cases}
(x, 0) & if n = 0 \\
(x, x/n) & if n \geq 1
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
is continuous and surjective. Since the continuous image of a compact space is also compact, to show that $Z$ is compact it would suffice to show that $X$ is compact. But I don't know how this could be.
Any help is appreciated.
Not so coincidentally, this is an example from Munkres. I have included the image which displays $X$ and $Z$ for the readers' convenience.


A subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded. Do you want to prove the result without using this?

Unfortunately for you, $X$ is not compact. Indeed, $([0,1]\times\{n\})_{n\in\Bbb N_0}$ is an open cover with no finite subcover - or, by Heine-Borel, it fails to be compact since it is clearly unbounded. This is related to Munkres' proof that $f$ is not a homeomorphism; why does $(1/n,n)_n$ have no limit point? This could not happen in a compact metric space (Bolzano-Weierstrass, metric space is sequentially compact iff. it is compact).
So, what can we do? More simply we can use Heine-Borel for $Z$ directly. It is easy to see $Z$ is bounded. Say $(z_m)_{m=1}^\infty$ is a convergent sequence in $Z$, convergent to $\zeta\in[0,1]^2$. Suppose $\zeta\notin[0,1]\times\{0\}$ i.e. $\zeta_2>0$. If $N$ is so large that $1/n<\zeta_2$ for all $n>N$, it is clear from the definition of the $Z_\bullet$ and of convergence that $z_m\in\bigcup_{k=1}^NZ_k$ for all sufficiently large $m$. But as finite unions of closed sets are closed, it follows $\zeta\in Z$. In the other case, $\zeta\in[0,1]\times\{0\}\subset Z$; in all cases, $\zeta\in Z$ as desired. Thus $Z$ is closed.
A similar style of argument could directly prove $Z$ is compact, without recourse to the Heine-Borel theorem. Hint: cover $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ first, then do a similar thing and get a finite cover of $\bigcup_{k=1}^NZ_k$ for some suitably large $N$.

$X$ is unbounded hence not compact. $Z$ is clearly bounded. To prove it is compact, there remains to show it is closed. For this, just notice that $Z=[0,1]^2\setminus U$, where
$$U:=\{(x,y)\in(\Bbb R^*)^2\mid x/y\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Z\}$$
is an open subset of $(\Bbb R^*)^2$ (hence also of $\Bbb R^2$), as the inverse image of an open subset of $\Bbb R$ under a continuous map.
